# Converting into interrogative sentence

Tags: grammar, questions

Situation : A mom cooks a meal for her son, and the meal is ready. The son comes and asks his mom.

> Is the meal ready ?

My question : please correct this sentence to a more colloquial question that a native English speaker would use every day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think native speakers would ask about the status of the *meal*. It's a perfectly understandable word, but not really used in that context. I'd substitute what kind of meal it is, instead:

> "Is breakfast ready?"
>
> "Is lunch ready?"
>
> "Is dinner ready?"

Or even the name of the food:

> "Is the pot roast ready?"

Answer (score 2):

That sounds right enough.

I'd probably say: "Is my meal ready yet?"

The usage of "my" indicates that it is his meal.